# How to hide/show more text within a forEach loop

Tags: php, jquery

My code is :

```
<?php 
$msgArray = [
0=>'HTTP means HyperText Transfer Protocol.',
1=>'HTTPS,Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Secure is the secure version of HTTP.'
];
foreach ($msgArray as $key => $msg) :
$small = substr($msg, 0, 5);?>
<span class="lessText"><?= $small ?></span>     
<span class="fullText" style="display: none"><?= $msg ?></span> 

<sub class="viewMore" style="color:#3399ff;padding-left2%;cursor: pointer;">view more >></sub>
<sub class="viewLess" style="color:#3399ff;padding-left2%;cursor: pointer;display: none"><< view less</sub>
<?php endforeach; ?>   

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".viewMore").click(function(){
$(".viewMore").hide();
$(".lessText").hide();
$(".fullText").show();
$(".viewLess").show();
});

$(".viewLess").click(function(){
$(".viewLess").hide();
$(".fullText").hide();
$(".lessText").show();
$(".viewMore").show();
});
</script>
```

Here, I am trying to display a long string to its 1st five character and after clicking *view more* it will be displayed the whole string.
this is working fine if there is only one. Inside the **forEach** loop its not working properly. Please solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the HTML fragment in a container.

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="lessText"><?= $small ?></span>     
    <span class="fullText" style="display: none"><?= $msg ?></span> 

    <sub class="viewMore" style="color:#3399ff;padding-left2%;cursor: pointer;">view more >></sub>
    <sub class="viewLess" style="color:#3399ff;padding-left2%;cursor: pointer;display: none"><< view less</sub>
</div>
```

Then modify your script to use DOM traversal method to target the desired element. Using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverse up to common parent i.e.  `container` then using it as [context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) or use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(".viewMore").click(function () {
    var container = $(this).closest('.container')   
    $(".viewMore, .lessText", container).hide(); //container.find('.viewMore, .lessText').hide()
    $(".fullText, .viewLess", container).show();
});

$(".viewLess").click(function () {
    var container = $(this).closest('.container')   
    $(".viewLess, .fullText", container).hide();
    $(".lessText, .viewMore", container).show();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Write it in this structure:

```
<?php foreach(): ?>
<div class="holder">
 <div class="lessText"></div>
 <div class="fullText"></div>

 <div class="viewMore"></div>
 <div class="viewLess"></div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**JS**:

```
$('.holder .viewMore').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.holder').find('.lessText').hide();
  $(this).closest('.holder').find('.fullText').Show();
 });

 $('.holder .viewLess').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.holder').find('.lessText').Show();
  $(this).closest('.holder').find('.fullText').hide();
 });
```